# Flutter web url query parameters removed on initial load

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am hosting a flutter web app, which involves the initial url having query parameters (e.g. https://mysite.web.app/?k=ZF6K5UA7X3Jk9HJanla3). I use the [url_strategy package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy) to get rid of the #, however when the site loads, the query params are stripped off, leaving the bare-boned "https://mysite.web.app". I have got around the functionality aspect by storing the param as a cookie variable, however it is not ideal.

Is there any way to re-instate the params programmatically in the url bar of the browser? The reason for this is for both (i) giving the user the option to share the original URL, and (ii) allow them to add the app to their mobile device screen as a PWA (with the original full url).

Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this via the implementation of [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). With the combination of `state.queryParams` and `Router.neglect(context, () => context.go('/?k=$myOriginalParam'))` (from any pages that wanted to go back to the original route with no browser back button history), I can retain the query parameter in the browser bar successfully.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code?